# Unable to Push Project to Remote NotFastForwarding?

Tags: java, git, netbeans

I have a project that I haven't been able to push for a while due to an error in my Netbeans version.

As a result, there have been many commits that haven't been able to be applied to the remote server on github.

When I try to push the project I get this error message: [image: Error], which terminates with the log entry:

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : fcf9817a37a891fe0458ec9ff001c6fbc8538315
New Id        : 2500a6b6033591739b383de8f6444161521401c6
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

```
Local Repository Updates
==[IDE]== 1 Aug 2018, 13:35:39 Pushing - StellarOPUSConverter-master finished.
==[IDE]== 1 Aug 2018, 13:41:19 Pushing - StellarOPUSConverter-master
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://SarahSzabo@github.com/SarahSzabo/StellarOPUSConverter refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : fcf9817a37a891fe0458ec9ff001c6fbc8538315
New Id        : 2500a6b6033591739b383de8f6444161521401c6
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
==[IDE]== 1 Aug 2018, 13:41:43 Pushing - StellarOPUSConverter-master finished.
```

From what I've read about other similar posts on the site, the way how people generally tend to get around this is by first pulling and then pushing the project.

When I try pulling, it says that I have a bunch of conflicts, which I resolve by selecting Accept` on the modifications that are from the most recent commit. When I try to push it though, I get the same error as before I pushed it.

Branch Structure:
[image: Branch Structure]

Video of it here:
https://youtu.be/NnBLv-b2ZEk

How can I resolve this issue and update the git repository?

Comment: Have you tried `git pull --rebase && git push` ?

Comment: @Bit-Man Yes, I have. It had no effect.